# Postgres: how to group by item in range efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, group-by, range

Suppose I have schema with all intervals items were active:

```
item_active
- item_id    -- id, foreign_key to item.id
- date_from  -- timestamp
- date_to    -- timestamp
```

I want to group by how many items were active on each day from `date1` to `date2`. I can do it by joining dates subquery:

```
with sq as (
    select generate_series(date1, date2, '1 day'::interval)::date dt
)
select sq.dt, count(distinct item_id)
from sq
join item_active 
     on item_active.date_from::date <= sq.dt
        and item_active.date_to::date >= sq.dt
group by sq.dt;
```

This works well, but execution time linearly depends from days count in `(date2 - date1)`, O(N). So the more days I want to group by, the slower execution I have.

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=213338137.82..216968937.32 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=7220.689..8938.530 rows=5 loops=1)
  Group Key: sq.dt
  CTE sq
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.029 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=213338132.81..214548398.65 rows=484106333 width=8) (actual time=6745.165..7054.655 rows=4623322 loops=1)
    Sort Key: sq.dt
    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 81352kB
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..123648051.46 rows=484106333 width=8) (actual time=0.035..5994.225 rows=4623322 loops=1)
          Join Filter: (((item_active.date_from)::date <= sq.dt) AND ((item_active.date_to)::date >= sq.dt))
          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 17161463
          ->  CTE Scan on sq  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.039 rows=5 loops=1)
          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..122921.36 rows=4356957 width=20) (actual time=0.005..415.443 rows=4356957 loops=5)
                ->  Seq Scan on item_active  (cost=0.00..75606.57 rows=4356957 width=20) (actual time=0.011..382.122 rows=4356957 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.165 ms
Execution time: 8963.670 ms
```

Maybe there is more efficient way to get the same result?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added explain analyze

Comment: Does query execution time improve if you `SET enable_seqscan = off`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no

Comment: You could improve performance slightly if you increase `work_mem` and get rid of the disk sort. Do you have an index on `date_from, date_to`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I have index on `(date_from::date, date_to::date)`. Slightly can't help a lot :)

Comment: Which Postgres version is that? Does an index on `(date_from::date, date_to::date, item_id)` help? Does the plan change if you run `analyze item_active` to update the statistics?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in fact, there was no index on `(date_from::date, date_to::date)` (my fault). After adding it performance improved up to 30%. But it still very slow.

Comment: The problem is that with a join condition like that, the only possible join strategy is a nested loop join, and the expense is bound to grow linearly with the number of days. Without rewriting the query, I can't think of optimizations beyon what @a_horse_with_no_name suggests. Perhaps you could use `generate_series` to transform your table into something that has a row per day instead of `date_from` and `date_to`. Then you can use `=` as join condition, and a hash or merge join would be possible, which might win for queries with many days.

Comment: Sometimes doing the join before grouping is faster: http://cryptb.in/yrr#a576d7e1dfa8877751bc077652facd7e

Comment: It is a pain point that the optimizer cannot estimate the number of rows returned from a function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name result even 7-10% worse

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow the item_active before join:

```
with sq as (
    select generate_series(date1, date2, '1 day'::interval)::date dt
)
select sq.dt, count(distinct item_id)
from sq
join (select * from item_active 
        where item_active.date_from::date <= (select max (sq.dt) from sq)
        and item_active.date_to::date >= (select min (sq.dt) from sq))
     on item_active.date_from::date <= sq.dt
        and item_active.date_to::date >= sq.dt
group by sq.dt;
```

Secondly try to disable nested loop:

```
set local enable_nestloop to false;
```

It should be replaced by hash or merge join - in some cases it could be faster.

If that doesn't help you should consider materializing this query to a view with

```
create materialized view
```